# How to apply .animate to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
var elementPosition = $(".total-value-bottom").offset();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
    $(".total-value-bottom").css("position", "fixed").css("top", "4.5em").css('left', '0em');


    $(".total").css("font-size", "70%");
  } else {
    $(".total-value-bottom").css("position", "static");
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  --white: #ffffff;
  --dusty-red: #ab3428;
  --black: #000;
  --grey: #808080;
  --green: #28ab34;
  --shadow: #00000044;
  --icbf-blue: #2d69a8;
  --border: #ccc;
  --icbf-green: #6ead2b;
}

.total-value-bottom {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px var(--shadow);
  background: var(--white);
  z-index: 2;
  height: 60%;
  width: 50%;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 70%;
  width: 76%;
}

.dash-flex-cell {
  padding: 11px;
}

.circle-total {
  border: 4px solid var(--icbf-blue);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.circle-amount {
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;
  /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;
  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 0.1em;
}

.circle-amount .amount {
  font-size: 130%;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: -5px;
  padding-bottom: 95%;
}

span.amountSpan,
.amountSpanTwo {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: var(--icbf-green);
}

.circle-amount,
.total,
.totalTwo {
  font-size: 76%;
  font-weight: 550;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container total-value-bottom">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="dash-flex-cell">
        <div class="circle circle-total">
          <div class="circle-amount">
            <div class="amount">
              <span class="amountSpan">10</span>
              <div class="total">Total Farm Emissions</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="dash-flex-cell">
        <div class="circle circle-total">
          <div class="circle-amount">
            <div class="amount">
              <span class="amountSpanTwo">2</span>
              <div class="totalTwo">CO2 Footprint</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container test-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="dash-flex-cell">
        <div class="circle circle-total">
          <div class="circle-amount">
            <div class="amount">
              <span class="amountSpan">4</span>
              <div class="total">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="dash-flex-cell">
        <div class="circle circle-total">
          <div class="circle-amount">
            <div class="amount">
              <span class="amountSpanTwo">2</span>
              <div class="totalTwo">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container test-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="dash-flex-cell">
        <div class="circle circle-total">
          <div class="circle-amount">
            <div class="amount">
              <span class="amountSpan">4</span>
              <div class="total">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="dash-flex-cell">
        <div class="circle circle-total">
          <div class="circle-amount">
            <div class="amount">
              <span class="amountSpanTwo">2</span>
              <div class="totalTwo">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container test-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="dash-flex-cell">
        <div class="circle circle-total">
          <div class="circle-amount">
            <div class="amount">
              <span class="amountSpan">4</span>
              <div class="total">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="dash-flex-cell">
        <div class="circle circle-total">
          <div class="circle-amount">
            <div class="amount">
              <span class="amountSpanTwo">2</span>
              <div class="totalTwo">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container test-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="dash-flex-cell">
        <div class="circle circle-total">
          <div class="circle-amount">
            <div class="amount">
              <span class="amountSpan">4</span>
              <div class="total">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="dash-flex-cell">
        <div class="circle circle-total">
          <div class="circle-amount">
            <div class="amount">
              <span class="amountSpanTwo">2</span>
              <div class="totalTwo">Test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Upon scroll, I was able to get my div to move with a fixed position and when you return to the position it was before it becomes static. However, when I first scroll it's a little rough (Jumpy), I'd like to apply animation to that so it's a bit smoother on the first scroll. I read that I can use .animate, but I am not sure how to implement it with my function.

```
    var elementPosition = $('.total-value-bottom').offset();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
            $('.total-value-bottom').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '4.5em').css('left', '0em');
            $('.total').css('font-size', '70%');
        } else {
            $('.total-value-bottom').css('position', 'static');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please add the relevant HTML and CSS to the question to create a working example of the problem. We can't fix a UI problem that we can't see,.

Comment: `$('.total-value-bottom').animate({position: 'fixed', top: '4.5em', left: '0em'});`

Comment: However, you have to calculate space after changing position to `fixed` somehow.

Comment: @mwl you can't animate the `position` property

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , Hi There, sorry I didn't have a working example, I just took the time to make one. https://codepen.io/winterlion/pen/WNzjbRX  So as you can see in the example on first scroll it's jumpy..

Comment: Sounds like you might actually want `position: sticky` ...? https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/

Comment: @CBroe , I tried sticky, but it's still giving me that hard jump on the first second of scrolling, I am hoping to ease it in on scroll or animate it lightly if that makes any sense :/

Comment: Main problem with the switch from `static` to `fixed` here appears to be, that the content is left aligned afterwards, instead of centered. You could fix that, by switching from `left: 0` to `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)` And then you should be able to simply animate the `top` value afterwards.